# How can I remove stagnant Exchange 2010 MoveRequest when the target DB is no longer available?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010

I inherited a server that was running a move request to a new mailbox database. Unfortunately the server died a horrible fiery death during this move request (some genius set up a RAID 1+0 array with just two disks, and only one connected...) and I was unable to restore from a recent backup.

Since I recovered from a dated backup, the server has been running fine for over 12 months, with the exception of one user. He is unable to access his mail account on his phone (he can access his email via Outlook fine). All other users can access email via their phones, except this one user. The move request is the only visible difference from the rest of the users.

I have tried (unsuccessfully) to resume the move request. This did not work as expected. I tried to remove the move request and this again did not work. Both require the target mailbox database to be online. Unfortunately, I do not have this and thus the move request can never complete.

Is there a way I can force the move request to abandon?

Comment: Also, the ActiveSync issue might have nothing at all to do with this; what diagnosis have you done on the CasMailbox and ActiveSync device registrations for the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried the below answer, but it seems reasonable as a starting point for your own investigation.

http://www.nonstop.co.il/kb/view.php?kb=66

> Solution
>
> 1. Open ADSIEDIT and navigate to the OU where your broken user account is stored.
> 2. Locate the user account, right-click on it and then choose "Properties".
> 3. Click on the "Filter" button and make sure "Show only attributes that have values" is checked.
> 4. Scroll down the attributes and search for an entry called "msExchMailboxMoveRemoteHostName".
> 5. Click on the "Edit" button.
> 6. Click on the "Clear" button.
> 7. Click the "OK" button.

Comment: Thanks for this. This was exactly what I was looking for. Although, that entry in step 4 was not set, it allowed me to find the msExchMailboxMove[...] attributes and clear them out.